# How to create offset slide-out dialog overlay

Tags: flutter, dialog

I'm trying to create an animated effect where a dialog box appears, and upon receipt of information, expands *down* to show it as opposed to *up and down*. (I'll explain below)

This is what I want. Notice the top stays fixed, and the bottom slides out. I'm not sure how to approach it due to the fixed top part of the dialog box. (Is there a way to offset a dialog?
[image]

But the closest I can get is this:
[image]

So, this is my code for the popup:

```
void showSites(BuildContext context) {
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0))),
        elevation: 0.0,
        content: SitePopUp());
    showDialog<void>(
      barrierDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert; 
      },
    );
  }
```

and the general structure of the pop-up build method inside SitePopUp() (without Padding, etc):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Site selectedSite;
    return Container(
          width: 700,
          height: (selectedSite == null)?200:700, // <-- TODO: Animate this on callback
          child:
              Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
            Text("Agency Directory",
            LookAhead(
                  lookAheadCallback: (List<String> val) {
                    selectedSite = siteList.getSiteFromAgencyNumber(
                        agencyNumber: selectedAgencyNum);
                  }),])); }
```

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: I must not have explained myself well. I’m trying to have the bottom information ‘slide out’ from the top. Therefore, when the top is shown, it needs to be offset towards the top in order to be centered when full size